# How to get Summarizer output in file

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter. I want to get Summarizer output to get test progress not in stdout.

```
(summary =      4 in   3,5s =    1,2/s Avg:  1012 Min:   999 Max:  1044 Err:     4 (100,00%))
```

for example a list contains these values

```
        ............
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault(
                "summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

    //  String TestResut=Summariser.format(null,null,null);
        String csvFile = "filePath";
        MyResultCollector csvlogger = new MyResultCollector(summer);
        csvlogger.setFilename(csvFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], csvlogger);

        // Run Test Plan
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);

        jmeter.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize the list with 3 variables like below

```
vars.put("a","NA");
vars.put("b","NA");
vars.put("c","NA");
```

when you get values for those variables, put into variables like below.

```
vars.put("a","1/2S");
```

Finally write the values into the file like below:

```
FileWriter fstream;
BufferedWriter out;
fstream = new FileWriter(vars.get("summaryReportFile.csv"),true);
out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
String summary = "+vars.get("a")+","+vars.get("b")+","+vars.get("c")+"\n";
out.write(summary);
out.close();
fstream.close();
```